# JOOQ and PostgreSQL - call stored procedure with bytea parameter

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I have a toy stored procedure in postgresql.

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo(bar bytea) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN TRUE;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Since I want to call it from Java code, I've generated Java object representing database routine using `jooq-codegen-maven` plugin. When I call it:

```
def select = DSL.select(Routines.test([1,2,3] as byte[]))
context.batch(s).execute()
```

it fails due to lack of procedure matching given name and list of parameters' types. It turns out that jooq generates incorrect query:

```
select "public"."test"(X'010203');

function public.test(bit) does not exist
```

Should be:

```
select "public"."test"('\x010203');
```

or:

```
select "public"."test"(E'\\01\\02\\03'::bytea);
```

Do you have any suggestion for a workaround? The only requirement is to have `bytea` in the end, because I want to insert a row with `bytea` column
 into database.

The similar situation is for `smallint`s. Jooq generates incorrect query (does not cast value `::smallint`), so postgresql cannot match any procedure due to the type mismatch (integer given, but smallint expected). This case can be easily "solved" by changing parameter type to `int` and making the case in procedure's body.

Comment: Interesting. What's the motivation of batching this call? I suspect batching is a requirement to reproduce the issue, right?

Comment: Also, what jOOQ version are you using? I cannot reproduce this with the latest version (although another issue appears, related to batching)

Comment: @LukasEder 3.7.0, I'll try with the latest 3.7.1. I'm using batch because I want to call this method multiple times with different parameters.

Comment: Interesting, what's your configuration for `context`, then?

Comment: @LukasEder, OK, my question is invalid. The output of `DSL.select(Routines.test([1,2,3] as byte[])).toString()` was misleading - it prints `X'010203'` while in fact query uses `E'\\01\\02\\03'::bytea`. Therefore `bytea` works properly :)

The real problem are `null` values for arguments of types `smallint` and `real` (possibly also for other types). If you pass `null`, it is casted to `int` and `double precision` respectively, which leads to "procedure not found exception". I don't know whether it is postgresql or jooq fault.

Comment: I see - yes, when you print it, as it lacks dialect configuration, it applies a more standard inlining of binary data. Curious about the `null` issue, would you mind updating / editing your question with reproduction details?